# How do I add a custom claim to authentication cookie generated by OpenIdConnect middleware in ASP.Net Core after authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I have an ASP.Net Core application project which uses IdentityServer4 Hybrid Auth Flow. It is setup as follows,

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    }).AddCookie("Cookies")
      .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
      {   
          options.Authority = IdentityServerUrl;
          options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

          options.ClientId = ClientId;
          options.ClientSecret = ClientSecret;
          options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
          options.SaveTokens = true;

          options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
          options.Scope.Add("openid");
          options.Scope.Add("profile");
          options.Scope.Add("email");
          options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
          options.Scope.Add("ApiAuthorizedBasedOnIdentity");
          options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
          options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name;
          options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role;                  
      });

    //Setup Tenant Role based authorization
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationPolicyProvider, AuthorizationPolicyProvider>();

    services.AddProxy();
}
```

I'm able to authenticate and SaveTokens=true successfully saves the access token in the ASP.Net authentication cookie. Now I need to add a custom claim to this same authentication cookie from within a Controller Action (**Not via a middleware**) in my ASP.Net Core client project. Let's say the Index action of HomeController for example.

I also need this claim to persist in the authentication cookie so that it will persist across requests and controller actions.

I did some digging around and noticed that I could do this with ASP.Net Identity

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var claimsIdentity = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity);
    if (!claimsIdentity.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "your-claim"))
    {
        ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("your-claim", "your-value"));

        var appUser = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(appUser).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Authentication is done by the IdentityServer using ASP.Net Identity which is setup in that project. However to use SignInManager, UserManager, etc. in the client project I will need to bring in ASP.Net Identity into it.  Setting up ASP.Net identity and stores in the client project also, just to update the authentication cookie with an additional claim seems like overkill. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You certainly don't need to include ASP.NET Core Identity in your client project, but you can use it for inspiration on just how to achieve what you're looking for. Let's start by looking at the implementation of [`RefreshSignInAsync`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs#L161):

```
public virtual async Task RefreshSignInAsync(TUser user)
{
    var auth = await Context.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
    var authenticationMethod = auth?.Principal?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.AuthenticationMethod);
    await SignInAsync(user, auth?.Properties, authenticationMethod);
}
```

As can be seen above, this also calls into [`SignInAsync`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs#L187), which looks like this:

```
public virtual async Task SignInAsync(TUser user, AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties, string authenticationMethod = null)
{
    var userPrincipal = await CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
    // Review: should we guard against CreateUserPrincipal returning null?
    if (authenticationMethod != null)
    {
        userPrincipal.Identities.First().AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.AuthenticationMethod, authenticationMethod));
    }
    await Context.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
        userPrincipal,
        authenticationProperties ?? new AuthenticationProperties());
}
```

The two calls we are most interested in are:

1. `Context.AuthenticateAsync`, which creates an `AuthenticateResult` containing both the `ClaimsPrincipal` and `AuthenticationProperties` that were read from the cookie.
2. `Context.SignInAsync`, which ends up rewriting the cookie with a `ClaimsPrincipal` and associated `AuthenticationProperties`.

ASP.NET Core Identity creates a brand-new `ClaimsPrincipal`, which is usually taken from the database, in order to "refresh" it. You don't need to do this, as you're just looking to use the *existing* `ClaimsPrincipal` with an additional claim. Here's a complete solution for your requirements:

```
var authenticateResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync();

if (authenticateResult.Succeeded)
{
    var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)authenticateResult.Principal.Identity;

    if (!claimsIdentity.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "your-claim"))
    {
        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("your-claim", "your-value"));

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(authenticateResult.Principal, authenticateResult.Properties);
    }
}
```

The call to `HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync` will use the default scheme you've already set up in your configuration (`"Cookies"`) to get access to both the `ClaimsPrincipal` and the `AuthenticationProperties`. After that, it's just a case of adding the new claim and performing a call to `HttpContext.SignInAsync`, which will also use the default scheme (`"Cookies"`).

Comment: As in the `signInManager` `Identity` code, I had to specify `IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,` as the 1st parameter of `SignInAsync` else the new claim wouldn't be written to the cookie.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have UserStore in your project, and I you are just using UserManager then you can do it easily by inheriting UserManager and override the GetClaimsAsync method

```cs
public override Task<IList<Claim>> GetClaimsAsync(T user)
{
    // here you can return a list of claims and it will be in the cookie
    return base.GetClaimsAsync(user);
}
```

By the way the default implementation of the base.GetClaimsAsync(user); is to call the related UserStore, so you can just drop it if you don't have UserStore with UserManager.

The UserManager can be configured via the IdentityBuilder as so:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddUserManager<CustomUserManager>();
```

The order matters; be sure it is configured last so it is not replaced by the default implementation.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**

You would need to use `HttpContext.SignInAsync` method. Also, you would need to update the `HttpContext.User` with the new `ClaimsPrincipal` once you have added the additional claims to the user. Please see the code below:

```
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("your-claim", "your-value"));

// genereate the new ClaimsPrincipal
var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

// store the original tokens in the AuthenticationProperties
var props = new AuthenticationProperties();

// get the current tokens
var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
var refreshToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token");

// create the enumerable list
var tokens = new List<AuthenticationToken>
{
    new AuthenticationToken {Name = "access_token", Value = accessToken},
    new AuthenticationToken {Name = "refresh_token", Value = refreshToken}
};

//store the tokens
props.StoreTokens(tokens);

// update the thread's current principal as it is changed, otherwise 
// System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current is referring to the 
// ClaimsPrincipal created from the cookie on the initial request. This is required 
// so that the next instance of HttpContext will be injected with the updated claims
HttpContext.User = claimsPrincipal;
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;

// sign in using the built-in Authentication Manager and ClaimsPrincipal
// this will create a cookie as defined in CookieAuthentication middleware
await HttpContext.SignInAsync("your scheme", claimsPrincipal, props);
```

Please make sure you replace the "your scheme" with the scheme name you are using. I hope that helps.

**Option 2**

Rightly pointed out by @Ruard van Elburg that the above solution will override the access token. (**updated to allow storing the original token**)

If you are adding the claims straight after the user is SignedIn, you can use the `OnTokenValidated` event

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
        {
            var claim = new Claim("your-claim", "your-value");

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { claim });

            ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(identity);

            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: This will overwrite the access token when "your scheme" is replaced by "Cookies".

Comment: oh yes, you are right. I was somehow thinking of the usual cookie authentication scenario. I think `OnTokenValidated` event can be used to achieve the above. I have edited the answer.

Comment: But how will the updated answer allow me to add a claim from within a controller action?

Comment: I guess you are adding the claims straight after the user is SignedIn, then you may not need to add at the controller level. However, if you really need to do add the claims within a controller action,  I realised that you can store the existing tokens in the `AuthenticationProperties` and call `HttpContext.SignInAsync` using the updated `AuthenticationProperties` again. This way the original tokens will not be overridden. I have edited my original answer. Please have a look. I haven't had a chance to test, please let me know if that works for you.